# File loss due to unexpected reboot during write on f2fs filesystem

Tags: linux, filesystems, flash, embedded

I am using F2FS in embedded linux (eMMC flash), and I noticed a lost of logs if device was unexpected rebooted. I have wrote a program that writes to a file in a loop and at one point causes a reboot of the device. After reboot the file is missing on flash. mount options are default (I tried to specify other options but this did not have an effect).
I tried to use EXT4 and error does not reproduce on it.
Is there any way to avoid file loss on F2FS filesystem, or I should use other FS?

Comment: You should fix your program so it doesn't cause a reboot...

Comment: The program is a test written to reproduce an error.
It only confirms the loss of files. In real word reboot causes by external reasons (e.g. sudden power loss) and causes the loss of real data.